# Dynamic String Replacement in Python using Format()

Tags: python, string, dictionary

Is there a way to dynamically format a string with `string.format()`, when the arguments can vary? I want to write a function where the inputs are a SQL string and a dictionary of name-value pairs; both inputs can vary.

So for example, a SQL string might be

```
"select * from students where school={schoolArg} and age={ageArg}"
```

with the dictionary being `{schoolArg: "some school", ageArg: 10}`

Another SQL string might be

```
"select * from teachers where class={classArg}"
```

with the dictionary being `{classArg: "history"}`

...and so on.

I can use `string.replace()` without problems. But is it possible to use `string.format()`, where the arguments is not known in advance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that **whatever database package you are using will already contain functionality for this**, which will be much more robust (to e.g. appropriate quoting/escaping *(quite bad)* and SQL injection [*(very bad)*](http://xkcd.com/327/)) than using basic string formatting.

See e.g. [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/902408/3001761)

Don't roll your own, **use the database API**.

---

That being said, you've almost done it already:

```
>>> "select * from students where school={schoolArg} and age={ageArg}".format(**{"schoolArg": "some school", "ageArg": 10})
'select * from students where school=some school and age=10'
>>> "select * from teachers where class={classArg}".format(**{"classArg": "history"})
'select * from teachers where class=history'
```

*(If the syntax is unfamiliar, see [What does ** (double star) and * (star) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/3001761))*

Note that, to reinforce the point above, you haven't correctly quoted your template string, so the output isn't a valid SQL query.

Comment: Wow, Python makes life so much easier! Regarding using database API, I will learn/read up on that. Thanks!